# AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python

```
with open(argv[1]) as csvfile:
    for character in csv.DictReader(csvfile):
        division_title = character.split()
        if len(division_title) < 3:
            db.execute("INSERT INTO students(first, middle, last, house, birth) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                       division_title[0], None, division_title[1], character[1], character[2])
        else:
            db.execute("INSERT INTO students(first, middle, last, house, birth) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                       division_title[0], division_title[1], division_title[2], character[1], character[2])
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File import.py, line 14, in <module>
```

[image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

try by modifying start code as:

```
with open(argv[1]) as csvfile:
    data = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for character in data:
        division_title = data[character].split()
```

Comment: TypeError: 'DictReader' object is not subscriptable

Comment: File "import.py", line 16, in <module> division_title = data [character].split()